Pull Logic to simulate Demand with the process modeling library
I am trying to simulate the movement of pallets in a closed loop pallet management system with one company being responsible for supply of pallets to industry customers and for the pickup downstream of the SC at the retailers.
I have trouble with the push logic of Anylogic.
This is the process so far: Process with all 3 parties
I am currently stuck to establish to establish a process, where only pallets are batched at the Industry Customer (and then transported etc.) if the GoodsInventoryR1 falls below a certain threshold.
My specific question is: how to make the batch block only accept agents if the variable GoodsInventoryR1 falls below a certain threshold?
I tried to create the pull logic with this code in the batch block.
I also tried to use an event, that is triggered if inventory falls below a certain threshold, but I fail to connect it to the queue or batch block.


My specific question is: how to make the batch block only accept agents if the variable GoodsInventoryR1 falls below a certain threshold?

You cannot do this in the block itself. Instead, use a block upstream that manages it for you. 2 quick ideas (there are many, depends on what you need):

a Hold block that only lets through agents under certain conditions
a SelectOuput block that only routes agents to your Batch block under certain conditions, else to somewhere else

